# 403 Forbidden - The page requires a client certificate as part of the authentication process

Tags: php, ssl, curl, soap, certificate

I am in the process of implementing a SOAP client in PHP. I have received a `.pfx` certificate from the remote company implementing the SOAP service.

When I import this `.pfx` in Chrome and open the WDSL file at: `https://api.test.remote.company.com/O/OMS.svc?singlewsdl`, I get an XML file indeed.

Since I need to use `.pem` certificates for PHP's `SoapClient`, I have converted the `.pfx` with the following:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in received.pfx -out converted.pem -clcerts
```

Since I was still facing issues with my client, I resorted to perform a test with Curl:

```
curl --verbose --cert converted.pem:MyPassphrase https://api.test.remote.company.com/O/OMS.svc?singlewsdl
```

But I get a 403 error message:

```
*   Trying 123.4.56.789...
* Connected to api.test.remote.company.com (123.4.56.789) port 443 (#0)
* found 173 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
* found 697 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* SSL connection using TLS1.2 / ECDHE_RSA_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
*    server certificate verification OK
*    server certificate status verification SKIPPED
*    common name: test.api.company.com (matched)
*    server certificate expiration date OK
*    server certificate activation date OK
*    certificate public key: RSA
*    certificate version: #3
*    subject: C=RU,ST=Moscow,L=Moscow,O=AO Company Lab,OU=IT,CN=test.api.company.com
*    start date: Tue, 31 May 2016 00:00:00 GMT
*    expire date: Thu, 08 Jun 2017 23:59:59 GMT
*    issuer: C=US,O=thawte\, Inc.,CN=thawte SSL CA - G2
*    compression: NULL
* ALPN, server did not agree to a protocol
> GET /O/OMS.svc?singlewsdl HTTP/1.1
> Host: api.test.remote.company.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.50.1
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden ( The page requires a client certificate as part of the authentication process. If you are using a smart card, you will need to insert your smart card to select an appropriate certificate. Otherwise, contact your server administrator.  )
< Connection: close
< Pragma: no-cache
< Cache-Control: no-cache
< Content-Type: text/html
...
```

Does anyone know what is happening and how it can be solved?

Comment: Can you try it with a PEM cert created with `openssl pkcs12 -in received.pfx -out insecure.converted.pem -nodes`?  That will create a cert that doesn't have an encrypted private key so it won't need a passphrase.  Obviously, treat that file very carefully...

Comment: I've just tried, but I am getting: `curl: (35) error reading X.509 key or certificate file: The certificate and the given key do not match.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following procedure to convert the `.pfx` certificate to `.pem` solved the issue:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in the.pfx -out cert.pem -clcerts -nokeys

openssl pkcs12 -in the.pfx -out key.pem -nocerts
```

Then merge the `cert.pem` and `key.pem` files into a unique file, without any addition.